# Tensorflow CNN - how to correctly build the dictionary of labels coupled to image stamps

Tags: python, audio, tensorflow

I am trying to load my data into [this tutorial model](http://%20https://github.com/mdda/deep-learning-workshop/blob/master/notebooks/2-CNN/8-Speech/SpeechRecognition_Learn.ipynb) to test it. I'm basically transforming a labeled audio file into a graphics file for classification through a CNN. But I am unsure about stamps and how the data is stored in the dictionary

Ad input I have a list with: 
file1.wav classlabel
file2.wav classlabel
file3.wav classlabel

The CNN classifier loads (unfortunately I don't have an example .pkl file to examine):

```
dataset = pickle.load(open(os.path.join('data', prefix+'.pkl'), 'rb'))

def batch_input_fn(dataset, indices, batch_size=100, seed=None, num_epochs=1):  
    # Get the data into tensorflow
    stamps = np.array( dataset['stamp'] )[indices]
    print("stamps.shape:", stamps.shape)
    labels = np.array( dataset['label'] )[indices]
    print("labels.shape:", labels.shape)
```

I am confused here, what does the stamp represent exactly? Below it seems like it's both class and label?

```
 def wav_to_stamp(prefix, word, wav):
    samples, sample_rate = soundfile.read( os.path.join('data', prefix, word, wav) )
    return samples_to_stamp(samples, sample_rate)


   for each wav file f that I have: 
        if not f.endswith('.wav'): continue
        #print(stamp_file)
        stamp = wav_to_stamp(prefix, word, stamp_file)
        # stamps are essentially images here created with stamp = scipy.misc.imresize(data_min0, (64, 32), 'bilinear')

   data_dictionary = dict(
    stamp=stamps, label=labels, 
   )

ds_file = os.path.join('data', prefix+save_as)
pickle.dump(data_dictionary, open(ds_file, 'wb'), protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

The above has been modified a bit to accommodate my data (no words and sentences, which are in the [read-in script](https://github.com/mdda/deep-learning-workshop/blob/master/notebooks/2-CNN/8-Speech/SpeechRecognition_Data.ipynb). But I am unsure is stamps and labels are couples correctly. How do I store them in data_dictionary correctly, so that each stamp has a label?

Comment: labels are words, and stamps are spectrogram of those words.